# Font lost in release apk Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make Google Fonts not lost when compiling an **apk**?
When I have the build **apk** it is correct but when I release it it has the default font:

| **release apk** | **build apk** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: release apk] | [image: build apk] |

Comment: Is your app native, or are you using a framework/tool (cordova, ionic etc)?

Comment: @vr_driver he's using Flutter like the title says. zhyk are you using the Google Fonts pub dev library? or an URL?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla i used pub dev lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because google font requires internet access to load the font.

To give your release app version internet access, you have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the `<application>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

`Project Folder > android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml`